# How to "Send as attachment" as default in Inbox by Gmail?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I would like to send images as attachment by default in Inbox by Gmail. Is it possible to define this as a default setting?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not currently.

I recommend sending feedback to request this feature be implemented. Here is video on how to leave feedback for Inbox by Gmail: https://youtu.be/9J_DIGvaW3k?t=49s.

If more people take time to submit feedback, it is more likely that the feature will be implemented. To make it really easy, feel free to copy and paste the following:

> Please provide an option to default to "Send as Attachment" when adding adding photos to emails. I would like to be able to default to "Send as Attachment" on desktop browsers as well as mobile apps.

I did not include a screenshot when I left feedback.

Ref: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/inbox/0CG0U95MQds